# Get value from people picker

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, peoplepicker

How how can I get the value from a people picker control?

```
 if (colListItem.get_item(User).length > 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < colListItem.get_item(User).length; i++)
  {
  //Append all User names with a semi colon separator

               _User = _User + colListItem.get_item(User)[i].get_lookupValue() + ";";
                }
                        _User.trim;
                }
                }
            }
```

This works if there is more than one value in the people picker control.
But if there is only one value, I am unable to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it from:

```
if (colListItem.get_item(User).length > 1)
```

To:

```
if (colListItem.get_item(User).length >= 1)
```

If there is only one value, only the second one will be true.

Comment: Hi, I know how to check the length. I need to know how to get the value.

Comment: look at your logic... you saying
if(more then one){do stuff}
I say...
if(one or more then one){do stuff}